What else besides immensely powerful muscles would allow someone to run faster than the speed of sound?
For context: In my game's lore, I have a line of genetically enhanced humans that are meant to be used as bioweapons in the military. Not particularly original, I know, but bear with me. The muscles of these humans are all kinds of insane. A single gram of their muscle when contracting at full force can develop pressures that are thousands of times more intense than the pressures in the earth's core (1.5PPa vs 360GPa). The force-velocity and force-length curves, normally a serious bottleneck for athletic performance in our real life athletes, are completely absent in these souped up muscles, meaning they can contract with full force at any length and at any speed. Basically, these muscles are absurdly powerful.
If a human had these muscles, what else would they need to be able to breach the sound barrier while running without changing them into something unrecognizable as human? I assume durability in the body's tissues to withstand such otherworldly stresses will be required, but other than that, does this human need anything else to be able to achieve such a feat? What would the challenges in running at that speed be like? Do they need anything else to successfully pull this off, or are the incomprehensible forces that such muscle can exert enough to propel the person to that speed without any extra help? (Note: They don't have to accelerate to the speed of sound in something ridiculous like in one stride, they can slowly speed up until they break the sound barrier)
I've looked at other similar questions, but those had somewhat different environments, such as the atmosphere being Hydrogen Chloride, and focusing more on body lengths per second rather than the physical parameters required for a being to run at such great speed. Answers also typically converged on jet power, I'd like to know if exceptionally powerful legs can get the job done, if that makes sense

I don't know why aerodynamics became flight, that was not the tag I put in when I wrote this question. I have since removed the tag

For the young-uns:  https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/carmageddon/  (Sorry about the fact-checkers)

Would massive ears that act as airfoils be OK?

We regularly host questions asking for help scientifically explaining superpowers (aka magic). It doesn't work. What would the body need? bones made of titanium, joints about 10X their current size and made of ceramic, a form of lubrication that doesn't exist in the body at all, not larger muscles but faster reacting muscles and then a brain and nervous system that can react at those speeds, skin made of heat-absorbing tile.... The creature wouldn't be human. Have you thought about how such a person would turn? Airplanes at mach 1 need miles to make a 90° turn, banked so the 1G turn...

... doesn't harm the pilot. Looking at any superpower through the lenses of science proves they're complete fantasy - as they were intended to be. If you want a science-based superpower you're looking at the Batman, a normal human with corporate resources that allow for really cool toys that sometimes mimic superpowers.  But just an everyday human being, nonetheless. So, what changes must occur? Consider the kind of human that stepped into the ThrustSSC and broke the sound barrier... in a car. (Na-na-na-na-na-na-na-na-Batman!)

I once wrote a story with a character running at insane speeds... but it was fantasy, with magic.  Do that in a [tag:science-based] or even a [tag:science-fiction] setting, you'd have the ground and the runner's shoes - and feet - being ablated.

No matter how powerful their muscles are, they won't be able to push forward with a force larger than the friction force between the soles of their shoes and the ground. This won't get them anywhere near the speed of sound.


A single gram of their muscle when contracting at full force can develop pressures that are thousands of times more intense than the pressures in the earth's core

All that force is pointless if there is nothing which can absorb it. Imagine having a dragster trying to sprint on a ice surface with slick tires, and you get a very partial image of what your heroes will face.
As soon as they try to sprint full force, the ground will crumble under their feet, their bones would crumble too, unless also the bone can somehow withstand those load.
And then, in order to be able to run at speed X, you need to be able to move your feet at speed 2X, because you need to be able to recall the foot back for the next step. This would give quite some shock-waves on the legs and bodies of your heroes.


I have a line of genetically enhanced humans ... A single gram of their muscle when contracting at full force can develop pressures that are thousands of times more intense than the pressures in the earth's core (1.5PPa vs 360GPa).

You cannot do this with genetic enhancement of ordinary biology. Not by many orders of magnitude. The energy supplies just aren't there.
Further, these pressures exceed the tensile strength of any real material by many orders of magnitude. The muscles will snap as soon as they try to exert such forces, and the bones they exert these forces on will crumble in a way that looks a lot like an explosion.
Trying to implement comic-book super-powers with actual science doesn't work. We answer a lot of questions that come down to that, and the answer is always the same.

+1. Napkin math gets me some number typically expressed in kilotons of TNT. 1.5 PPa * working cross sectional area of human musculature * contraction distance.

Within the realm of sci-fi, you'd need something silly like gravity multipliers and an enormous spoiler on their back, and even that quite certainly wouldn't let them run faster than the speed of sound. The issue is always traction. Your superhumans simply can't exert enough force on the ground. The best you'll get is to have them push off of vertical surfaces to temporarily break the sound barrier.
A regular running form would also heavily limit their speed, as they'd spend far too much time in the air to accelerate properly. They'd probably "run" around with their chest parallel to the ground, and then pulling themselves along with their arms and push with their feet where possible. Since your superhumans are already deep into sci-fi territory, maybe have enormous spikes shoot out of their feet and arms into the ground, which they can push off of before they quickly retract.

So, unlike my other esteemed World Builders - I think the traction on the ground is not as big a deal.
Now, for clarity sake - I think this is impossible - but even on a slippery surface, you can still accelerate, it is just a very slow acceleration.
But lets go through the factors on the Human body - because I think this is both interesting and hilarious:
1: Air resistance
This is the first biggy. Going supersonic at ground level where the air is thickest is a big problem. Thrust SSC (which was very aerodynamically shaped) was still generating skin temperatures of 300 degrees C.
So first up, we are going to need skin capable of withstanding temperatures in excess of that due to Drag.
Next up we have Breathing. If you have ever stuck your head out of a fast moving vehicle and tried to breath in, you will notice that the air is forced into your lungs - at Supersonic speeds, an un-augmented human would literally burst their lungs from the speed of the air moving inwards.
then we have Eyes and skin (again) - I think this video paints a most amusing image: I do not condone riding without a Helmet on a Motorbike, much less doing 300 kph, but the visuals are relevant here - multiply that by 3-4 times
2: Friction
Runners Nipple and Chaffing - only in true spinal tap fashion, dialled up to 11. Since there is a limited amount of traction available on the ground, you would have to have a lot of steps - looking like an even more cartoonish version of the Flash - and that amount of Friction would burst a human into flames like Spontaneous human combustion.
But wait! There is more! inside the body - yeah, those joints, they are gonna be generating some serious heat with all that movement.
3: Internal stresses on the body
Ligaments, joints, bones, cartilage, synovial fluid, Hell, even the organs themselves - I read once that at a normal jog, the human body is exerting about 4 times your weight in pressure on a heel strike. that is about half a tonne of force for a fatass like me (and yes, I can Jog - 10 kph for an hour).
The observant will notice that 10 kph is significantly slower than the speed of sound - and so even if we assume a linear relationship - the body would be exerting something like 700 tonnes of force with each foot strike.
The G-forces that the limbs would experience - going forward at supersonic speed, then stopping and moving backwards - for a limb that weighs around 17 kg (the legs) that is equivalent to a Tank Shell (120 mm) being fired - which gives a G Force rating of around 100,000 G.
Next up, you know when you have to squeeze and relax your muscles when giving blood to help the blood flow - well the type of forces that your body would exert would mean that the circulatory system would be under such pressure (not to mention how hard the heart would have to pump to supply the muscles with enough blood etc.) that you would literally rupture from the inside from the insane pressure.
4: Energy
So, even if we managed to address all those other factors - the biggest one IMO is the Energy required to do this - Afterburners absolutely drink Jet fuel - something like 3-4 KG of fuel every second - which equates to about 172 MJ of energy required every second.
That is a lot of energy.
In short - These are the biggest factors alone that would need to be addressed, there are a myriad of other things like reaction time etc. but TL;DR - you would need to completely re-engineer a human to even get close - and as you can see, there are a number of significant challenges to overcome.
World Building suggestion
Consider a character like the Flash or the speedy one from XMen - although they occassionally nod to some of these problems - they simply state it is so and let the reader suspend disbelief.

Where there is lots of energy, there is also a lot of heat. Not only would your skin have to survive high temperature due to stagnation temperature plus friction. The internal temperature with all of the internal friction and requirement to dispose of less than 100% efficiency may be enough to require survival of temperature exceeding high hot joints and muscles - because you sure have no mechanism for disposing of the waste heat fast enough to prevent an extreme temperature rise.

Traction on the ground is indeed a problem, for the issue you raise as point #1.  Unless the friction force between their soles and the ground is greater than the force of air resistance (which it will not be well before the sound barrier is approached), they will be unable to accelerate further.
